# ARKit: How do you iterate all detected feature points?

Tags: swift, arkit

I'd like to do some processing for each of the detected feature points found in a single frame during an ARKit session.  How can I iterate through each of the detected feature points, and get their world coordinates?

I'm using Swift, but an Objective-C answer will be fine as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** In Xcode 9.0 GM (and later), [`points`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arpointcloud/2927814-points) is a Swift array of `float3` vectors, so you can iterate it like any other Swift array:

```
for point in frame.rawFeaturePoints.points { 
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
frame.rawFeaturePoints.points.map { point in 
    ... 
}
```

Or whatever your favorite Array/Collection algorithm is.

---

In various Xcode 9.x betas, the Swift Array version of this property wasn’t available. So instead you had to deal with the [underlying ObjC property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arpointcloud/2887448-points), which imports to Swift as an `UnsafePointer`, which you can’t iterate as easily. (Hence the OP’s original question.)

If that bug ever resurfaces (or you run across a similar problem elsewhere), you could do something like this:

```
for index in 0..<frame.rawFeaturePoints.count {
    let point = frame.rawFeaturePoints.points[index]
    // do something with point
}
```

Comment: Thanks rickster... do you know if I need to be concerned that it is an "unsafe" pointer?  Is the memory going to be changed out from under me or something?

Comment: Think “unsafe” more like a book of matches, not a bomb. It’s not going to spontaneously explode on you, but it is a way to burn yourself if you’re not careful. The main thing that’s unsafe about an unsafe pointer in cases like this is that with `points[index]` you can read right past the end of it and read memory that’s not supposed to be interpreted as a bunch of `float3`s, giving you junk. It’s “unsafe” in that the compiler won’t (and can’t) protect you from such errors, leaving your safety in your own hands. But you know the `count`, so you know how to make sure you don’t read too far.

Comment: Latest xcode beta has these fields as `__count` and `__points`, fyi

Comment: @rickster In Xcode 9.0+ using Swift 4.0 `ARPointCloud.points` looks to me like a regular Swift array. Has this recently changed or does the previous advice regarding `UnsafePointer`s still apply?

Comment: In an earlier Xcode 9 beta, `points` was an unsafe pointer. Apple eventually replaced that with a Swift-specific `points` array, but in some beta releases that wasn't present and the underlying ObjC properties appeared as `__points` and `__count`. I've updated the answer to reflect the current state of affairs, while still describing the mechanism as it might be useful in other cases (or if the Swift API gets out of sync again in future betas).

Comment: Why not put `for point in frame.rawFeaturePoints {  }`? Looks cleaner and saves a line...

Comment: @LinusGeffarth that’s what the edit/update to the answer is about — you can now use `for` or `map` or whatever just like any other array.

Answer (score 2):

As it took me a while to come up with a working sample of what it looks like to get a render of the feature points, here's a full working example:

```
SCNNode *ARPointCloudNode = nil;

- (void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0));
{

    NSInteger pointCount = frame.rawFeaturePoints.count;
    if (pointCount) {
        // We want a root node to work in, it's going to hold the all of the represented spheres
        // that come together to make the point cloud
        if (!ARPointCloudNode) {
            ARPointCloudNode = [SCNNode node];
            [self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:ARPointCloudNode];
        }

        // It's going to need some colour
        SCNMaterial *whiteMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
        whiteMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = YES;

        // Remove the old point clouds (this happens per-frame
        for (SCNNode *child in ARPointCloudNode.childNodes) {
            [child removeFromParentNode];
        }

        // Use the frames point cloud to create a set of SCNSpheres
        // which live at the feature point in the AR world
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
            vector_float3 point = frame.rawFeaturePoints.points[i];
            SCNVector3 vector = SCNVector3Make(point[0], point[1], point[2]);

            SCNSphere *pointSphere = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:0.001];
            pointSphere.materials = @[whiteMaterial];

            SCNNode *pointNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:pointSphere];
            pointNode.position = vector;

            [ARPointCloudNode addChildNode:pointNode];
        }
    }
}
```